# WAMP + XAMPP, localhost/phpmyadmin not accesible

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp

I am new to alot of things with `WAMP/XAMPP`, so i followed a few tutorials online, which required me to go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`. But every time i open the "webisite" i get an Error 404. As far as i know, no ports are blocked for either of the programs. when i start both apache and mysql on XAMPP it is highlighted green, and the ports are

```
Apache : 80, 443

MySQL : 3306
```

When i go to the WAMP icon, and test the port for Apache it says:

```
your port 80 is actually used by : 

Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.01l PHP/5.6.8
```

which in my eyes isn't a problem.

I installed XAMPP for limesurveys, which i want to host locally. So everytime i open localhost in my browser it loads a website where i can choose from surveys. This list is obviously empty, but the important information is, THAT the webisite is available. now when i try open `localhost/phpmyadmin` i get a website telling me about `Error 404` and stuff. I have checked, that phpmyadmin is installed when i installed WAMP, and also, that the alias in `C:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf` directs to the correct `folder` `C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/`. What im wondering is, why i cant open phpmyadmin...

Comment: Do u hav skype installed

Comment: nope. neither do i have teamviewer. like i said all ports are free, and the programs listen correctly to them

Comment: check `World Wide Web Publishing Service` is running or not in service. If running then stop

Comment: @russell310 i cant find it in the services list, so i guess it isnt running

Comment: uninstalling teamviewer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed both xampp and Wamp on your machine try uninstalling one and just work with either one, I would recommend xampp. Make sure you move all your work files from htdocs or www, if your are uninstalling xampp or wamp respectively. Then try turning apache and mysql on and see if it works.

Good luck!

Comment: what really struck me was, that when you click "Config" in the Apache Line in XMAPP it doesnt seem to have the listed phpmyadmin config anywhere. the only place i found phpmyadmin was with wamp, and even there it all looked weird.

Comment: go to the location where you installed xampp and go into the xampp folder and try to find a folder named phpmyadmin in there. if it exists go inside the folder and try to locate the file config.inc.php

if the folder is not there then you have installed xampp after you installed wamp and it ignored to install phpmyadmin alongside. Remove wamp and xampp both and then install xampp alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course keep both XAMPP and WAMP running together keeping in mind that you have changed the default ports for either of it to some other ports rather than 80,443 and 3306, but sometimes it could create conflict as when you install some other third party softwares or enable certain services  that run on port 80,443,3306.

The best alternative here would be to install one of the servers  inside a virtual machine with network configured as "host-only-adapter" so that from the base machine you could access XAMPP/WAMP installed on the virtual machine by just pointing the ip-address of the virtual machine through a web-browser.

or,

If you want to run both XAMPP and WAMP together on the same machine but access only one of the servers at a time then you could go ahead installing both of them one after another. But, keep in mind that before installing the other server you have to completely stop all the services running from the XAMPP or WAMP control panel then quit the application. After this step you can go ahead installing the other server without changing any configurations or port numbers. This is because in this case we assumed that only one of the servers would be accessed at a time. Hence, before launching the other server one has to completely quit the application that is running currently by stopping all of it's services. If skype is installed then one has to change the default incoming connection ports to other than port 80 and 443.

Like mentioned above, if at all the intention is to access both servers up and running concurrently then taking advantage of a virtual machine would be the best to avoid conflicts and a long-term troubleshoots eventually.

If you messed up changing ports and config files then you could end up with the following error while trying to access phpmyadmin from XAMPP control panel:

```
    **mysql said: Cannot connect: invalid settings. xampp**
```

**note:** *while launching the servers ,* **run it as administrator** *else some services will not start properly.*

**"I TRIED INSTALLING BOTH XAMPP AND WAMP ON WINDOWS 10 AS SUCH AS POINTED BY MANY THREADS I CHANGED THE DEFAULT PORTS FOR MYSQL & APACHE XAMPP AS IT WOULD CONFLICT WITH WAMP ALREADY INSTALLED ONLY ENDING UP UNABLE TO ACCESS PHPMYADMIN FROM XAMPP CONTROL PANEL. THEN REINSTALLED XAMPP WITHOUT CHANGING ANY CONFIGS OR PORTS. STOP THE WAMP SERVICES, QUIT THE APP AND THEN LAUNCH PHPMYADMIN FROM XAMPP CONTROL PANEL. AT LAST IT WORKED!. THE PROCESS LOOKS SHORT THOUGH WHEN IN REALITY IT TOOK ME COUNTLESS HOURS AND PAIN RESEARCHING ON THE WEB AND TESTING FOR A POSSIBLE SOLUTION UNTILL I CAME UP WITH THIS."**

Hopes, this quick tips and guides would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Stop all IIS services and Skype with generally use the same ports.

Comment: what are IIS services, and skype isnt even installed ;)